# Epigraphical Cones, Fenchel Conjugates, and Duality

Tags: convex-analysis, dual-cone

I'm trying to derive a result relating cones conceived as epigraphs of convex functions, duality, and Fenchel conjungates. Let me state exactly what I'm looking for:

Let $\mathbb{E}$ be an Euclidean space and let $f\colon\mathbb{E}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that 
$$K:=\text{epi}(f)=\{(x,t)\in\mathbb{E}\times\mathbb{R}\,\colon f(x)\leq t\}$$
is a proper (convex,closed,pointed, and with nonempty interior) cone. What is the relation between the Fenchel conjugate $f^\ast$ of $f$ and the dual cone $K^\ast$?

This was my (trivial) attempt until I got stuck:

Let $(y,w)\in\mathbb{E}\times\mathbb{R}$. Then $(y,w)\in K^\ast$ if and only if:

\begin{align*}
&\langle (x,t),(y,w)\rangle\geq 0 \text{ for each } (x,t)\in K\\\iff& \langle x,y\rangle+tw\geq 0\text{ for each } (x,t)\in K\\\iff& \langle x,y\rangle + f(x)w\geq 0\text{ for each }(x,t)\in K\\\iff& \inf_{(x,t)\in K}\{\langle x,y\rangle +f(x)w\}\geq 0 
\end{align*}

First, I'm not sure if I can substitute $t$ for $f(x)$ in the third line above and why this is correct, but I've seen several people taking this approach. For instance, Glineur uses the exact same technique in page 123 of [this text](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00006861/document). Moreover, I know that I'm quite close of finding something but I must be missing some silly detail on how to deal with $w$.

Does anyone have any source with a proof of this result or can help me finish my proof?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\<}{\left\langle}\newcommand{\>}{\right\rangle}\newcommand{\epi}{\operatorname{epi}}$

I do not think there is an elegant relationship. As an example, take $f(x) = |x|$, with $x\in \R$. Then $f^*(y) = \delta_{[-1,1]}(y)$, whose epigraph is not a cone.

There is a correspondence between the epigraph of $f$ and that of $f^*$, that is $(y, b) \in \epi f^*$ if and only if

$$
\<y, x\> - a \leq b, \forall (x, a) \in \epi f.
$$

If $f$ is lsc, then $f=f^{**}$ and we can apply this to $f^*$. Then $(x, a) \in \epi f$ if and only if

$$
\<y, x\> - b \leq a, \forall (y, b) \in \epi f^*.
$$

We can try to use this fact to determine $K^*$, but I think it becomes clear that there is no direct relationship between $K$ and $\epi f^*$:

\begin{align}
K^* 
{}={}&
\{(y,w) \in \R^{n+1} {}:{} \<(y, w), (x, t)\>\geq 0, \forall (x,t) \in \epi f\}
\\
{}={}&
\{(y,w) \in \R^{n+1} {}:{} \<y,x\> + tw\geq 0, \forall (x,t) \in \epi f\}
\\
{}={}&
\{(y,w) \in \R^{n+1} {}:{} \<y,x\> + tw\geq 0, \forall (x,t) \in \epi f\}
\\
{}={}&
\{(y,w) \in \R^{n+1} {}:{} \<y,-x\> - tw\leq 0, \forall (x,t) \in \epi f\}
\\
{}={}&
\{(y,w) \in \R^{n+1} {}:{} \<y,z\> - tw\leq 0, \forall (z,t) \in \epi \breve{f}\}
\\
{}={}&\{(y,w) \in \R^{n+1} {}:{} \<y,z\> - tw\leq 0,  \forall (z,t) : \breve{f}(z) \leq t\},
\end{align}

where $\breve{f}$ is the reversal of $f$ defined as $\breve{f}(x) = f(-x)$. The issue here is that we do not know the sign of $w$ in advance. For example, if we knew that $w > 0$, we would have

$$
K^* = \{(y, w): (y,0) \in \epi(w\breve{f})^*\}.
$$

Your question reminds me of the following property: $(u, -1) \in N_{\epi f}(x, f(x))$ if and only if $u \in \partial f(x)$. In this case, we would be interested in $N_{\epi f}(0,0)$. However, this result allows us to tell whether $(u,-1)$ is in $N_{\epi f}(x, f(x))$, so it does not offer a full characterisation of the normal cone. Note that $K^* = -N_{\epi f}(0,0)$.

In case you are interested, we can show that $K^*$ can be written as

$$
-K^* =
\{\lambda (v, -1) {}:{} v \in \partial f^*(0)\}
\cup 
\{(v, 0) {}:{} 0 \in \partial^\infty f(v)\},
$$

where $\partial^\infty f$ is the horizon subgradient of $f$, provided that $f$ is lsc. This is Theorem 8.9 in the book of Rockafellar and Wets.

By the way, since $\epi f$ is a cone, we know that it is positively homogeneous.